# Pattern.quote matches substring instead of whole word match

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern

I was trying to implement a case insensitive whole word searching pattern. I came up with the following pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.Compile('(?i)'+Pattern.quote('af'));
```

Using it in the code below:

```
String datum= 'Looking into  dataframe or DataFrame';

Pattern p = Pattern.Compile('(?i)'+Pattern.quote('af'));
Matcher m = p.matcher(datum);
while (m.find()) {
    Integer s = m.groupCount();
    for (Integer i = 0; i <= s; i++) {
        System.debug(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

It matches ***af, aF*** which are just part of word and is not an exact match.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not `Pattern.quote`, but rather your use of [Matcher.find](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_find):

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. This method returns true if a subsequence of the input sequence matches this Matcher object's pattern.

So `Matcher.find` skips non-matching data to find the next match.

Whole word matching requires you to use the word boundary matchers like `\b`, while whole input matching is achieved using [Matcher.matches](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_matches):

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

To find whole words, within the over-all input, containing certain character sequences you simply need to tweak your code thus:

```
String datum= 'Looking into  dataframe or DataFrame';

Pattern p = Pattern.Compile('(?i)\\b\\w*' + Pattern.quote('af') + '\\w*\\b');
Matcher m = p.matcher(datum);
while (m.find()) {
    Integer s = m.groupCount();
    for (Integer i = 0; i <= s; i++) {
        System.debug(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

This looks for a case-insensitive match against:

1. A word boundary
2. Followed by zero or more word class characters
3. Followed by your quoted search term
4. Followed by zero or more word class characters
5. Followed by a word boundary

Comment: What should I be using Instead?@philW

Comment: Entirely depends on exactly what you are trying to do. If you want to match the entire input, just use `Matcher.matches`.

Comment: I want to extract the words which are being matched.

Comment: Can you modify the code to match exact searches only, Like if the string only contains sf and not dataframe, since dataframe is being returned here. Thanks in advance

Comment: it also matches DataF+rame

Comment: I encourage you to read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm) and the related Java documentation for details as to what you can and cannot do with regex in Salesforce. It's not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to do. Do you want the search term to be a whole word? If so, simply remove the zero or more word class character parts from my example (i.e. the `\\w*` before and after your quoted search term).

Comment: Note the double backslash is required since backslash is an escape character in Apex strings and we need Apex to leave it as a backslash for regex. It becomes a single backslash from the regex perspective since Apex replaces "\\" with a single backslash.